# Facebook login after releasing Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

During debug, facebook login works well using debug hash key applied on developer's App setting and admin as login. But when it is exported/released and corresponding generated release key (using keytool) is added in the setting, it is not working for other public facebook profiles. I have also printed the release key and it matches. Does Facebook has to grant public access for the app to make it work? As the status on facebook developer is negative for below question: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to turn the status to public. Otherwise it's only available to users with Administrator, Developer, or Tester roles.